# How to create the folder to store the downloaded files in iOS using xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to download the pdf file and trying to view it from my app using xamarin.forms. I am able to create a path in android device but not able to create the path on the iPad. I need to create the custom folder and need to download the files in that directory. How to achieve that.

```
string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileBytes);

               byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = DecodeUrlBase64(DataString);

               string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

               string finalPath=Path.Combine(documentsPath, Path.GetFileName(fileFullPath));

               Directory.CreateDirectory(finalPath);

               File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, encodedDataAsBytes);
```

Comment: this should work the same in iOS and Android as long as you are using a user writable path.  Please show the relevant code that is not working

Comment: I Have updated the code I am using, could you please have a look at that

Comment: according to the docs CreateDirectory will throw an exception if you pass it a file path, which is what you appear to be doing

Comment: But is there any option other than that, Could you please let me know that if any other way is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine when I removed `CreateDirectory`, Following are the changes to my code which is working as I expected

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = DecodeUrlBase64(DataString);

                string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                string finalPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, Path.GetFileName(fileFullPath));

                File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, encodedDataAsBytes);
```

Comment: is it work for ios?